# ExtJS: How to access a DIV element by id

Tags: html, dom, extjs, element

I have a variable in EXTJS as follows ->

```
var test = '<html><body><div class="myDiv">
This is a test div.
</div></body></html>';
```

How can I access the class/id to manipulate it? 
I tried following and none of them worked.

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');
var dom = Ext.dom.Query.select('.myDiv');
var el = Ext.get(dom[0]); 
Ext.getCmp('myDiv').getEl();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with gets elementsbyclassname

[getElementsByClassName()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp)

for example:

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("myDiv");
var myDiv = x[0];
```

If you want to use the document.getElementById() function, you need to get an id to de div:

```
var test = '<html><body><div class="myDiv" id="myDiv">
This is a test div.
</div></body></html>';
```

**EDIT FOR EXTJS**

You can try with

```
Ext.query(".myDiv")[0];
```

if you want to use the class, or with

```
var test = '<html><body><div class="myDiv" id="myDiv">This is a test div.</div></body></html>';
Ext.get('myDiv');
```

if you want to use the id.

Comment: Thank you @Juan. The solution worked in regular HTML editor but looks like extjs doesn't have document.getElementsByClassName or document.getElementsById. What can I use in EXTJS to achieve same result

Comment: @KavitaC You can try with Ext.query(".myDiv")[0]; if you want to use the class, or with var test = '<html><body><div class="myDiv" id="myDiv">This is a test div.</div></body></html>'; Ext.get('myDiv'); if you want to use the id.

Answer (score 2):

Assign an 'id' attribute to the div tag, document.getElementById("myDiv") will match this.

```
var test = '<html><body><div id="myDiv" class="myDiv">
```

Comment: Thank you @Colin. The solution worked in regular HTML editor but looks like extjs doesn't have document.getElementsByClassName or document.getElementsById. What can I use in EXTJS to achieve same result

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you made an error.
Your html variable was fine.

This is what you used to call *myDiv*:

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');
```

When it should have been:

```
var myDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('myDiv');
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you @Imagifight. The solution worked in regular HTML editor but looks like extjs doesn't have document.getElementsByClassName or document.getElementsById. What can I use in EXTJS to achieve same result